# How to install psiphon-tunnel-core wtih domain fronting support?

Tags: linux, vpn, ssh-tunnel, vpn-client, point-to-site-vpn

I need install psiphon tunnel core with domain fronting support
https://github.com/Psiphon-Labs/psiphon-tunnel-core

I researched everywhere but I can't find any detailed tutorial or document for this software
I researched page too but install instruction extremely outdated :( 
https://bitbucket.org/psiphon/psiphon-circumvention-system